# Foundation Grid shows differently in Experience Editor mode

Tags: sxa

I have used Foundation grid to create the site. After that created the page, but it's showing the small area (small css classes) during page edit in experience mode and also after publish its not covering the complete page:

**Foundation Grid:**
[image]

**While Bootstrap Grid covering complete page:**
[image]

**Foundation Page output:**
[image]

Please let me know, is there any settings needs to be changed for Foundation grid, so that it will cover whole page.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's how the foundation grid works. It's more grid specific setting rather then SXA one. But thanks to the fact that SXA supports different grid system there is an option to customize this.

Just navigate to your theme item and look for PlaceholderSettings field:

[image]

Change settings from Fixed to Flex for one of the placeholders or to all of them. Here I've just changed this to the Main placeholder and this gives me something like that:

[image]

By changing those settings you change the CSS class which is assigned to the certain placeholder. Those classes are defined per grid system. For the Foundation grid they are defined here: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Foundation/Grid Definition`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. After updating the Placeholder settings to site specific grid, i am able to see that extra "expanded" css class added into each container div (header/main/footer).